# How execute Listener class every time i receive requests on my servlet

Tags: java, servlets, listener, web.xml

When receiving requests on my servlet, i would like execute one listener class which is related with, and which contains some instructions.

So i implement on myListener the interface ServletContextListener, like this:

```
public class MyContextListener implements ServletContextListener {

    @Override
    public void contextDestroyed(ServletContextEvent arg0) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    }

    @Override
    public void contextInitialized(ServletContextEvent arg0) {
        System.out.println("Context Created");
    }

}
```

On my web.xml :

```
  <servlet>
    <servlet-name>StartUp</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>com.servlets.StartUp</servlet-class>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
  </servlet>
  <servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>StartUp</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/StartUp</url-pattern>
  </servlet-mapping>

  <listener>
    <listener-class>com.servlets.MyContextListener</listener-class>
  </listener>
```

So how can i execute my listener, when receiving requests on my StartUp servlet ?

Answer (score 5):

The [`ServletContextListener`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/servlet/ServletContextListener.html) is designed to listen on initialization and destroy of `ServletContext`. In other words, it's only invoked on webapp's startup and shutdown respectively.

You need a [`ServletRequestListener`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/servlet/ServletRequestListener.html) instead:

```
@WebListener
public class MyRequestListener implements ServletRequestListener {

    @Override
    public void requestInitialized(ServletRequestEvent event) {
        System.out.println("Request initialized");
    }

    @Override
    public void requestDestroyed(ServletRequestEvent event) {
        System.out.println("Request destroyed");
    }

}
```

Or, perhaps just a simple [servlet filter](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/servlet-filters/info). The difference is that you can configure it to listen on specific URL patterns or specific servlets and even specifically forwarded, included and/or error'ed requests.

```
@WebFilter("/StartUp") // or @WebFilter(servletNames={"StartUp"})
public class StartUpServletFilter implements Filter {

    @Override
    public void doFilter(ServletRequest req, ServletResponse res, FilterChain chain) throws IOException, ServletException {
        System.out.println("Before StartUp servlet is invoked");
        chain.doFilter(req, res);
        System.out.println("After StartUp servlet is invoked");
    }

    // Don't forget the init() and destroy() boilerplate.

}
```

Comment: +1. As an addition (because your answer is more complete): [Java EE 6: Defining the Listener Class](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/tutorial/doc/bnafi.html#bnafk), [Java EE 5: Defining the Listener Class](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/5/tutorial/doc/bnafi.html#bnafk)